# How to refactor XSLT template to make it reusable

Tags: xml, xslt, refactoring

I have following template, creating an xml. There are multiple similar code blocks in one template. There is just one element value depending on on of the parent element name. And i have a suspection about using `if test` instead of just `template match` were also a not perfect idea? But how then?:

```
   <xsl:template match="Adresse">
    <!-- TelefonG  -> "Telefon Geschäftlich" (ID = 1) -->
    <xsl:if test="TelefonG != '' or TelefonGZus != ''">
      <xsl:if test="PersonGuid != ''">
        <xsl:element name="AdrKontakt">
          <KontaktGuid>
            <xsl:value-of select="commonFunctions:createGuid()"/>
          </KontaktGuid>
          <PersonGuid>
            <xsl:value-of select="commonFunctions:convertGuid(PersonGuid)"/>
          </PersonGuid>
          <InfoText>
            <xsl:value-of select="commonFunctions:toHtmlEntities(TelefonG)"/>
          </InfoText>
          <Kommentar>
            <xsl:value-of select="commonFunctions:toHtmlEntities(TelefonGZus)"/>
          </Kommentar>
          <xsl:element name="KontaktTypID">1</xsl:element>
          <xsl:the-same-crap/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>

        <!-- TelefonP   -> "Telefon Privat" (ID = 2) -->
        <xsl:if test="TelefonP != '' or TelefonPZus != ''">
          <xsl:if test="PersonGuid != ''">
            <xsl:element name="AdrKontakt">
              <xsl:the-same-crap/>
              <xsl:element name="KontaktTypID">1</xsl:element>
              <xsl:the-same-crap/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- TelMobil -> "Telefon Mobil" (ID = 3) -->
        <xsl:if test="TelMobil != '' or TelMobilZus != ''">
          <xsl:if test="PersonGuid != ''">
            <xsl:element name="AdrKontakt">
              <xsl:the-same-crap/>
              <xsl:element name="KontaktTypID">3</xsl:element>
              <xsl:the-same-crap/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:and-so-on/>
```

the input xml look like here:

```
...
<Adresse>
  <PersonGuid>THEGUID01234567890</PersonGuid>
  <TelefonP>0878938493</TelefonP>
  <TelefonPZus>Some text about this number</TelefonPZus>
  <TelefonG>9309340934</TelefonG>
  <TelefonGZus>First class customer.</TelefnoGZus>
  <TelefonM>090923409</TelefonM>
  <TelefonMZus>Mobile because not always in office.</TelefonMZus> 
  <Email>abuse@bad.com</Email>
  <EmailZus>suspect</EmailZus>
  <!-- and so one -->
</Adresse>
<Adresse>
  <Email>bla@foo.bar</Email>
  <TelefonM>0298309283</TelefonM>
<Adresse>
...
```

How would you refactor it to write the same crap just onse? Some switch case? E.g. TelefonP => 1; TelMobil => 3, etc. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: To really find the optimal way we would need to see a sample of the input document. It would also help to know what `<xsl:the-same-crap />` is, exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I supposed it is not important. Now i have just expressed it exactlier. the-same-stuff are some transformations of the TelefonXXX elements which calls the c# code from commonFuctions module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would add a second template in addition to your current one to ignore **Addresse** elements with no **PersonGuid**

```
<xsl:template match="Adresse[PersonGuid = '']" />
```

This is because in all your three templates you only output new elements where there is a **PersonGuid**. This would simplify the code in the template then as you could drop the respective **xsl:if** on this condition.

Note that in this case, XSLT will always give priority to the more specific template here.

As for re-factoring the code, I think you can just use an **xsl:choose** here, but positioned within the **AdrKontakt** you are outputing.

```
<xsl:template match="Adresse">
 <AdrKontakt>
    <xsl:the-same-crap/>
    <KontaktTypID>
       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="TelefonG != '' or TelefonGZus != ''">1</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="TelefonP != '' or TelefonPZus != ''">1</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="TelMobil != '' or TelMobilZus != ''">3</xsl:when>
       <xsl:choose>
    </KontaktTypID>
    <xsl:the-same-crap/>
 </AdrKontakt>
</xsl:tempalte>

<xsl:template match="Adresse[PersonGuid = '']" />
```

Do note, there is no real need to use **xsl:element** to output new elements here, just output the element directly.

EDIT: If you need to output multiple **AdrKontakt** then you call probably make use of a named template, with a parameter, to contain your repeated code:

The named template would look like this:

```
<xsl:template name="AdrKontakt">
 <xsl:param name="KontaktTypID" />
 <AdrKontakt>
    <xsl:the-same-crap/>
    <KontaktTypID>
       <xsl:value-of select="$KontaktTypID" />
    </KontaktTypID>
    <xsl:the-same-crap/>
 </AdrKontakt>
</xsl:tempalte>
```

And to call it, you would just do this:

```
<xsl:template match="Adresse">
  <xsl:if test="TelefonG != '' or TelefonGZus != ''">
      <xsl:call-template name="AdrKontakt">
          <xsl:with-param name="KontaktTypID" select="'1'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="TelefonP != '' or TelefonPZus != ''">
     ...
```

And so on for your other conditions. You would not be able to eliminate your **xsl:lf** but your repeated code would now only occur in one place.

Note that, within the named template **AdrKontakt** your current context will still be the **Adresse** element, and so you can still have output other elements as currently:

```
<xsl:template name="AdrKontakt">
 <xsl:param name="KontaktTypID" />
 <AdrKontakt>
    <InfoText>
       <xsl:value-of select="commonFunctions:toHtmlEntities(TelefonG)"/>
    </InfoText>
    <KontaktTypID>
       <xsl:value-of select="$KontaktTypID" />
    </KontaktTypID>
 </AdrKontakt>
</xsl:tempalte>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use an additional template for missing values. I was aware about, but would never get it myself. But my xml can have multiple occurences of e.g. TelefonG and TelefonP. I need to emit some elements for each of it. The xsl:choose creates just one value. Would be here better some applytemplate with variable, or another template instead?

Comment: AH, I see! Yes, you could use a named template here. I've extended my answer with an example of this.

Comment: So i will not overcome "if test"? And how to get a value of corresponding subelements TelXXX and TelXXXZus within the named template?

Comment: No, you would still need the **xsl:if** conditions, because the purpose here is to eliminate the repeated code. Note that I've extended my answer to show how to get other values in the named template.

Comment: Ok, I think i get it now. I can do so for PersonGuid, because it is always the same. Additionally in my case i just need some more template params. Because it need values of different elements for each contact type.

Comment: BTW: Note that the empty string evaluates to false in XPath, so that you can use `<xsl:if test="TelefonP or TelefonPZus">` (etc).

Comment: Big thanks for all you hints and examples. I think the provided solution is good enough.